# Django is not taking input from html POST form

Tags: python, html, django, post

I have this html form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="inputText">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value = required />
            <br><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" placeholder="Password" required />
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
            <br><br>
            <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="send">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="register" />
        </div>
```

This is my forms.py :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

And my view

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save
        new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password =request.POST['password'])
        login(request.new_user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request, '/index')
else:
    form = UserForm()
return render(request, 'authen/register.html', {'form': form})
```

This should be a register system but when I press register it reloads the register page and nothing. When I go to django admin I see no new user so django is not taking input from form fields.

Answer (score 3):

The form is presumably not valid, but you are not displaying any errors in your template. At least do `{{ form.errors }}` somewhere, although really you should output all the fields and their errors from the Django form directly:

```
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.username.errors }}
```

etc.

Also note you are not actually invoking the save method in your is_valid block. You need to do:

```
form.save()
```

Comment: After I add those, it says this field is required at the password fields so it doesn't take input from those.

Comment: You've named the password fields in your HTML template "pass1" and "pass2". Django has no way of associating those with the actual password field. Also note you don't have any code to validate that pass1 == pass2.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to `get` the input element by its `name` attribute. This is because `request.POST['keyword']` refers to the element identified by the specified html `name` attribute `keyword`.

Here's an example:

`<form action="/login/" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search query">
  <input type="number" name="results" placeholder="Number of results">
</form>`

In your Python file, where you get the value of the input elements, `request.POST['keyword']` and `request.POST['results']` will contain the values of `keyword` and `results`, respectively.